# Asp.net Allow access to Admin Only

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, session, admin, session-variables

I have a admin page in the secret folder and it should only be accessed by an admin. The way I attempted was creating a session and check if the logged in person is admin. This failed to recognise the admin. Following is what I attempted. Can anyone see where I went wrong? ***Is it because the admin page is in a different folder and when I created the session it wouldn't recognise it when I access the admin area? If so, how can i overcome this?***

```
if (Session["username"] != "admin")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/NotAdmin.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        showtables();
    }
```

Comment: What is failing the boolean or the redirect? Or is it the idea that is not working right entirely?

Comment: @Nomad101 the idea is not working. When logged in as "admin", it will just redirect me when it should've been allowing me access. Failed to recognise the admin

Comment: are you using standard webforms?

Comment: check the answer by @NikolaMitev which is what I was going to post if you were.

Comment: Will you only ever have 1 admin user? In the future it's worth looking into roles.

Comment: @Fishcake atm yes, only 1 admin. Thanks I will do look into it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the username via HttpContext class

```
    var user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    if (user!= "admin")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/NotAdmin.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
       showtables();
    }
```

In my opinion sessions are not good to work with it. What if your application is hosted on a load balanced server. If the server is being load balanced, your users will lose their session state information when the load balancer sends their request to another server.

Comment: Thank you Nikola. This works :) But how come it doesnt work with session?

Comment: Although this appears to have solved the problem your fears about load balancing are completely unfounded. If your website is hosted on load balanced servers then simply switch your state management from InProc to SQL Server or a State server. Certainly no need to not use session variables!